# Mongodb query debugging in Robo 3T

Tags: mongodb

I have very big mongo db query, how can we debug the query in Robomongo 3T or Robomongo or python or anywhere. i have query like below and how can we know in a loop which value is it coming?, can we use print statements or console.log.

```
{"$project":{
  "APChange":{
    "$map":{
      "input":{"$range":[0,{"$size":"$chg"}]},
      "as":"i",
      "in":{
        "$let":{
          "vars":{"ele":{"$arrayElemAt":["$APChange","$$i"]}},
          "in":{"_id":"$$i","APTCChange":"$$ele.APChange"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: No, you can't evaluate the aggregation while it is running. You've to run it to see what it outputs.

Comment: @VenkatB if your previous question was answered, please accept the answer provided, that will give you (and the answer) some reputation, and will show to future users that the answer solved your question.

Comment: oops, i forgot to accept the previous question answer, thanks Veeram @Alejandro Montilla